# I'm trying to write a script for smooth scrolling nav links but it just jumps directly to the anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "tof_css.css" />
<script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Kanit|Heebo|Source+Sans+Pro:200">

<script src="finaljs.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "container">

<header>
  <div id = "static_nav">
    <nav class = "navbar">
      <a href = "#block_one">HOME</a>
      <a href = "#block_two">ABOUT</a>
      <a href = "#block_four">PEOPLE</a>
      <a href = "#block_five">CONTACT</a>
      <a href = "">LOG IN</a>
    </nav>
   </div>
</header>

<div id = "block_one">
</div>

<div id = "block_two">
test
</div>

<div id = "block_three">
test
</div>

<div id = "block_four">
test
</div>

<div id = "block_five">
test
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Here is the Jquery:

It doesn't scroll at all. I tried referencing "nav" but that didn't work either. I'm not sure if my logic here is correct or if I'm missing something entirely.

```
$("navbar").find("a").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var section = $(this).attr("href");
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(section).offset().top
});
});
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where almost there, but in your code

```
$("navbar") // is nothing
```

you need to write

```
$("nav.navbar")
```

or

```
$(".navbar")
```

See working code here:

```js
$("nav.navbar").find("a").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var section = $(this).attr("href");
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(section).offset().top
});
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "container">

<header>
  <div id = "static_nav">
    <nav class = "navbar">
      <a href = "#block_one">HOME</a>
      <a href = "#block_two">ABOUT</a>
      <a href = "#block_four">PEOPLE</a>
      <a href = "#block_five">CONTACT</a>
      <a href = "">LOG IN</a>
    </nav>
   </div>
</header>

<div id = "block_one">
</div>

<div id = "block_two">
test
</div>

<div id = "block_three">
test
</div>

<div id = "block_four">
test
</div>

<div id = "block_five">
test
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I understand where I went wrong it makes sense. I ran it in jsfiddle and it worked but in browser it doesn't so I think it might just be my browser. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`$("navbar")` refers to an tag named `navbar` you instead need to to target the element with class `navbar`, hence use `$(".navbar")` to target the element

Comment: Thank you for the help. Very simple oversight on my part.